# Problem with backend matplotlib when exporting program with pyinstaller

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyinstaller

My code is plotting graph from excel documents (or csv) and then saving them automatically. It uses tkinter as an user interface.

I have a problem with matplotlib backend when trying to export my program with pyinstaller : I know this is a known issue. I have been trying to resolve it reading other comments, help on github : [Here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2785#issuecomment-601053163)

But I am a beginner and can't understand it.

---

I tried several things :

1 - Deleting and re-installing matplotlib, updating it

2 - in my code, using the command `import matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg`

---

I found some comments about solutions like this :

A -

```
try:
    # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
    base_path = sys._MEIPASS
except AttributeError:
    # If not running from a PyInstaller bundle, use the current working directory
    base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

# Append the filename (e.g., "ffmpeg.exe") to the base path
ffmpeg_path = os.path.join(base_path, "ffmpeg.exe")
```

B -

```
import nltk                                              # hook for nltk
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files   # add datas for nltk

datas = collect_data_files('nltk', False)

for p in nltk.data.path:                                 # loop through the data directories and add them
    if os.path.exists(p):
        datas.append((p, "nltk_data"))
```

But I don't know what it does and so can't really link this to my code, I tried to put this just raw at the beginning but it did not solve my issue.

---

The error message I get is

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "matplotlib.backends.backend_svg"
Failed to execute script "myscript.py" due to unhandled exeption!
```

Note that this is only at the end of the program that this message appear, all the other parts (besides saving pictures) work.

---

Edit : With further Trials and errors, I now see that the problem is due to the svg format. Maybe it is not possible to use the "classic" backend with svg files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found my error, this is actually really simple when you think about it :

```
import matplotlib.backends.backend_svg
```

I did not know this worked like that